How to define an interface with a required key-value pair?
I am trying to write an interface for a specific function that will take in an object and perform some intended functionality. I would like to type the input to ensure it follows a specific shape.
When I go to build such an interface, I would expect my code to work, but at compile it complains, "Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"message"'."
interface BodyInterface {
    settings?: any;
    body?: Array<Message>;
}

interface Message {
    type: MessageTypeType;
    text: string;
}

type MessageTypeType = "message";

const inputBody = {
    body: [
        {
            type: 'message',
            text: 'hello world'
        }
    ]
}

const caller = (body: BodyInterface) => {
    console.log(body)
}

caller(inputBody)

How can I declare this interface so that the body is expected to be an Array with contents that are objects with type: 'SOME_EXPLICIT_VALUE'?

Your variable's type is being widened, with type becoming string instead of 'message'. Use as const on your variable to prevent widening, and make the BodyInterface.body readonly to satisfy mutability constraints.

TS Playground

TypeScipt uses type inference to provide type information when there is no explicit type annotation.
const a = 1 is inferred as "number"
const b = "something" is inferred as "string"
In your case,
const inputBody = {
  body: [
    {
      type: "message",
      text: "hello world",
    },
  ],
}

is inferred as:
const inputBody: {
  body: {
    type: string;
    text: string;
  }[];
}

That explains the error:
"Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"message"'."
You can solve this in many ways, depending on your needs.
My suggested option is declaring your variable with the proper type annotation:
const inputBody: BodyInterface = {
  body: [
    {
      type: "message",
      text: "hello world",
    },
  ],
}

That way, you are telling TypeScript that this variable will always be a BodyInterface, instead of trying to infer the type from the initial values.
